# relogin in bash script with submitting password

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, su

How can I login to another account in bash script with password?

I try such command:

`su - test
 expect "password: "
 send "$pass"`

But it doesn't work

Comment: Do it as root.  Then you won't need the password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something along the lines of

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set USER test
set PASS password_of_test

spawn su - $USER
expect "*assword:"
send $PASS
send "\n"
interact
```

**NOTE**

I would strongly suggest that you **do not store passwords in plaintext**; a much better solution would be to use `sudo` to run commands as a different user.

Comment: Your path to `expect` might be different; please check with `which expect`.

Comment: I got "no expect in (...)"

Comment: Do you have `expect` installed on your system?  What do you get when you just type `expect` at the command prompt?

Comment: looks like I haven't installed expect, how can I do it?

Comment: Which is your system?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 (Tikanga)
Kernel \r on an \m

Comment: Then a `yum install expect` will do.  But you will need root permission to run it.

Comment: i have installed expect, but error still the same spawn: command not found

Comment: What does `which expect` spit out?

Comment: Ok, this is correct.  Then please grant execution rights to your script (`chmod +x yourscript.exp`) and invoke it as `./yourscript.exp`.

Comment: I done this, but error the same, but I noticed in your example executable script has extention .exp, my has .sh, does it matter?

Comment: It does not matter in a strictly technical sense, but it could be misleading.  It looks like your shell is trying to execute the script, instead of passing control over to the Expect interpreter.  As a last resort, try invoking it as `expect yourscript.exp`.